# Explain: "3% annual cost of renting is less than the 9% annual cost of owning"

Tags: mortgage, financial-literacy, housing

I was reading this: http://patrick.net/housing/crash1.html and found this statement by Patrick:

> 3% annual cost of renting is less than the 9% annual cost of owning
>   the same thing

Source: http://patrick.net/forum/?p=16284

I understand the statement but how did he come up with 3% and 9% values? I am not sure how can I reason about this statement.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The 3% and 9% figures are based on the cost of borrowing money and all the other ownership costs associated with real estate.

From the same article: http://patrick.net/housing/crash1.html

> Because it's usually still much cheaper to rent than to own the same
>   size and quality house, in the same school district. In rich
>   neighborhoods, annual rents are typically only 3% of purchase price
>   while mortgage rates are 4% with fees, so it costs more to borrow the
>   money as it does to borrow the house. Renters win and owners lose!
>   Worse, total owner costs including taxes, maintenance, and insurance
>   come to about 8% of purchase price, which is more than twice the cost
>   of renting and wipes out any income tax benefit.

Imagine you are renting a house. If the cost of your annual rent is lower than X then renting is obviously the best idea from a monetary calculation. If rent is greater than Y being a landlord makes more sense. In the middle it is debatable, and the non-monetary reasons need to be considered.

Answer (score 10):

The house that sells for $200,000 might rent for a range of monthly numbers. 3% would be $6000/yr or $500/mo. This is absurdly low, and favors renting, not buying. 9% is $1500/mo in which case buying the house to live in or rent out (as a landlord) is the better choice. At this level "paying rent" should be avoided. 
I'm simply explaining the author's view, not advocating it.

A quote from the article -

> annual rent / purchase price = 3% means do not buy, prices are too
>   high
>
> annual rent / purchase price = 6% means borderline
>
> annual rent / purchase price = 9% means ok to buy, prices are
>   reasonable

Edit to respond to Chuck's comment -
Mortgage rates for qualified applicants are pretty tight from low to high, the 30 year is about 4.4% and the 15, 3.45%. Of course, a number of factors might mean paying more, but this is the average rate. And it changes over time. But the rent and purchase price in a given area will be different. Very different based on location. See what you'd pay for 2000 sq feet in Manhattan vs a nice town in the Mid-West.

One can imagine a 'heat' map, when an area might show an $800 rent on a house selling for $40,000 as a "4.16" (The home price divided by annual rent) and another area as a "20", where the $200K house might rent for $1667/mo. It's not homogeneous through the US. As I said, I'm not taking a position, just discussing how the author formulated his approach.

The author makes some assertions that can be debatable, e.g. that low rates are a bad time to buy because they already pushed the price too high. In my opinion, the US has had the crash, but the rates are still low. Buying is a personal decision, and the own/rent ratios are only one tool to be added to a list of factors in making the decision.

Of course the article, as written, does the math based on the rates at time of publication (4%/30years). And the ratio of income to mortgage one can afford is tied to the current rate. The $60K couple, at 4%, can afford just over a $260K mortgage, but at 6%, $208K, and 8%, $170K. The struggle isn't with the payment, but the downpayment.

The analysis isn't too different for a purchase to invest. If the rent exceeds 1% of the home price, an investor should be able to turn a profit after expenses.

Comment: This answer is just wrong. Patrick is advocating renting a house to live in, not comparing buying to rent with buying to live in.

Comment: @DJClayworth - I said the comparison was buying a home to live in vs renting. I did not mean to imply otherwise.

Comment: These percentages seem useful, but they do not reflect prevailing mortgage interest rates.  The assumption in the referenced article seems to suggest approx 4% for mortgage rate.  But rates are low now compared to historical values; should rates rise, that should affect the purchase decision.  The article claimed that house prices would fall when rates rise, and also did not consider changes in rent prices.

Comment: @ChuckCottrill - I've edited to respond to your comment.